# What's the best classical physics (mechanics, electromagnetism, etc) textbook to read as a regular book?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Looking for recommendations for someone who loves physics but is not in college/university. I'm a 39-year old engineer.

Comment: it depends on how much math you want. If you don't mind the math, I recommend the classic Berkeley Physics Series (in four volumes).

Comment: Is the Halliday and Resnick a good book? Or University Physics is better?

Comment: I used H&R 49 years ago and it was OK.

Comment: @Qmechanic : not sure this is really a dupe of the link.  This one is much more specific and somewhat more basic.  I agree that your link should be there if this is what OP needs, but really understood the Q as much less specialized.

Comment: Hi Eddie Bravo (with Cc to @ZeroTheHero):  Res. recom. is restricted on Phys.SE. The post (v2) is _too broad,_ so I'm closing it.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Six ideas that shaped Physics](http://www.physics.pomona.edu/sixideas/) by Thomas Moore.  Every volume in the series just *oozes* physics, emphasizing symmetries and how the physics flows from some core concept.

It’s written at the first year University level, but I think it’s too rich in physics for the typical 1st year student mostly interested in just passing a required course.